# iphone Slider example

Tags: iphone

I'm making an slider application. For that, I have written the following code, but when I press on build and go option then the slider bar is not moving. It gives an error in the .h and .m file.

**SliderAppDelegate.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SliderAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    UIWindow *window;
    IBOutlet UISlider *slider;
    IBOutlet UILabel *labelTxt;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *labelTxt;

-(IBAction)changeSlider:(id)sender   ;
@end
```

---

**SliderAppDelegate.m**

```
#import "SliderAppDelegate.h"

@implementation SliderAppDelegate

@synthesize window,labelTxt ;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{   
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}

-(IBAction)changeSlider:(id)sender 
{
    labelTxt .text= [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@" Value %d ", (int)slider.value];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [window release];
    [label.Txt release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Are there any problems in this code?

Comment: What error are you receiving? Try removing the space before the `.text` property. And please enclose all of the code in the code tags. There's a button in the toolbar.

Comment: There are no code tags, you indent each line with 4 spaces.

Comment: which event u set with uislider in interface?

Comment: Change the question title please, i came here for slider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Inspire48 suggested make the changes to your code and also make sure the IBOutlets and IBActions are connected properly. Also check if the slider's action is connected to the event "Value changed".
You can also change your code to this

```
-(IBAction)changeSlider:(id)sender 

{

    labelTxt.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@" Value %d ", (int)slider.value];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comment from Inspire48, remove the space in `labelTxt .text` and change the `[label.Txt release];` to `[labelTxt release];`.

You have a memory leak in the changedSlider method. The initialized string isn't released.

And maybe you should read a book about objective C.